# Shiny errors due to the very large data size

Tags: r, shiny, bigdata

I've created a Shiny app which works fine for 1MM records. However, when I ran it using 5MM records, I keep getting some errors, such as the one below, which is due to the need to increase the storage capacity of R.

```
Warning: Error in : cannot allocate vector of size 533.6 Mb
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to run Shiny app on very large datasets? Any codes that might be useful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't need all the data at once, you can consider using an SQL database and communicate with it using `RSQLite`. This way, you go easy on your RAM.

Comment: Is it caused by the upload of a file ?